# Where do I add a zero as padding for 4B5B code?

Tags: bit, crc

I am trying to use the 4B5B Manchester encoding on a 15-bit word. Now if needed we are supposed to add **0** to the **end** of bit sequences as padding.

I am currently studying for a Computer Networks exam and one question makes us go through CRC for 2 5-bit words with a 6-bit long Generator Polynomial. The dataframe to be transmitted will then be 15 bits long (the two original words and the 5-bit checksum) We then have to use 4B5B on it, but this does not work on numbers that are not multiples of 4.

The Question tells us to add zeroes at the end of bit sequences as padding. Obviously, we only need one "0", but this is where we are unsure.

What is exactly the end of a bit sequence?
Is it

- the least significant bit, so on the right side of the word,
- or immediately after the checksum,
- or is it at the MSB, on the left side of the sequence, where it would not change the ''number'' (if reverted back into decimal)

Comment: "end of the bit sequence" implies the last bit that is transmitted or received. The 4 bit to 5 bit conversion would need to occur before adding a 5 bit CRC, but it's not clear at what stage of transmission or reception the CRC is used and when 4 bit | 5 bit mapping occurs.